# Blank logs on error with Verbose 4 using PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile

Tags: powershell, logging, invoke-sqlcmd

Can someone please help me understand why the second Invoke-SqlCmd doesn't log anything even though it encounters an error?
I am using **PowerShell**.

**What can be done to overcome this?**

Log file:

[image]

1. (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "PRINT 'Hello World!';" -ServerInstance $Server -verbose) 4>> 'C:\Users\Username\Execute Config\MyResultFile.txt'

   No Errors
2. (Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile 'C:\Users\Username\Execute Config\ABC.sql' -ServerInstance $Serve -verbose) 4>> 'C:\Users\Username\MyResultFile.txt'

   Error:

   [image: Error from second line of code]

Comment: Since your scripts seem to be different, are you sure both write in the verbose stream anyway?

Comment: @vonPryz Idon't know how to be sure,  I'm new to powershell. I ended up using transcript to log everything into te log.